# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: for conda env

Tags: python, ioerror

In my Python script `main.py`, I read a csv using pandas like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./input/input.csv')
```

My setup looks like this:

```
project/
   src/ 
      input/
         input.csv
      output/
         output.csv
      main.py
```

When I try to run my Python script from within the `src`folder, it runs smoothly. However, when I do this from my `project`folder:

```
python src/main.py
```

it throws an error

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './input/input.csv'
```

What am I missing out on? It's literally the same script

Comment: The problem is the current working directory. Enter the src folder and then run python main.py.

Comment: Yes but what's the problem? I want to be able to run it from the main folder Generally, it works @SimoX

Comment: I bring you the solution below which in a simple comment is difficult to explain.

Answer (score 0):

```
""" main.py """

import pandas as pd
import os

crr_dir = os.getcwd()       # get the cwd
os.chdir(crr_dir + '/src')  # change the cwd
print(os.getcwd())          # check the new path

df = pd.read_csv('./input/input.csv')  # now you can run this!
```

With this code you can call main.py from the project folder (`python src/main.py`). If you have other needs, simply change your working dir with os.chdir().